# Como pasar un array a una función en BASH - SCRIPTING BASH

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, shell-script

Estoy intentando pasar unos arrays a una función en bash pero no lo consigo.
He mirado varias formas de hacerlo pero parece que no funcionan.
La última forma que he probado es esta:

```
dependencies=( "build-essential" "git" ...)

insDepends "${dependencies[@]}"

function insDepends(){
name=( "@" )
for depend in "${name[@]}";do
apt install $depend -y > /dev/null
done
}
```

Más o menos la idea resumida es esta, alguien me puede decir como lo tengo que hacer?
Gracias de antemano !

Answer (score 2):

Te pongo dos opciones:

Tenemos dos funciones, el primero crea una variable con el contenido de "lunes" y un array con el contenido de "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo"

Luego llamamos a la función "metodoUsarVariableArray()" y le enviamos la variable y el aray por parámetro

```
metodoDeclararVariableArray()
{
    variable="lunes"
    array=( "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo" )
    metodoUsarVariableArray ${variable} ${array[@]}
}
```

La función "metodoUsarVariableArray()" recibe el contenido de la variable y el array por parámetro y los guarda en la variableNueva y el arrayNuevo respectivamente

```
metodoUsarVariableArray()
{
    variableNueva="${1}"
    shift
    arrayNuevo=("${@}")

    #imprimimos los valores recibimos por parámetro y almacenados en las nuevas variable "variableNueva" y matriz "arrayNuevo"
    echo "${variableNueva}"
    echo "${arrayNuevo[*]}"
}
#para que funcione el código anterior tendremos que llamar al primer método
metodoDeclararVariableArray
```

En éste segundo código:

"metodoDeclaraciónArrays dias[@] meses[@]" enviamos una "copia" del contenido de las matrices dias y meses a la función "metodoDeclaracionArrays()"

La función "metodoDeclaracionArrays()" recibe dias[@] y meses[@] como cadenas:

```
$1 == dias[@] y $2 == meses[@]

metodoDeclaracionArrays() { 
    declare -a arrayPrimero=("${!1}") 
    echo "${arrayDias[@]}" 

    declare -a arraySegundo=("${!2}") 
    echo "${arrayMeses[@]}" 
} 
metodoDarValoresArrays() { 
    local dias=( 
        "Lunes" 
        "Martes" 
        "Miercoles" 
        "Jueves" 
    ) 

    local meses=( 
        "Enero" 
        "Febrero" 
        "Marzo" 
        "Abril" 
    ) 
    metodoDeclaraciónArrays dias[@] meses[@] 
} 
metodoDarValoresArrays
```

EDITADO

Prueba así

El código está probado y funciona salvo en la línea de la instalación, que me arroja un error por cada iteración, si te da error también deberías de revisar esa línea. Aunque evidentemente en mi caso no tengo el sistema de ficheros que utilizas y puede deberse a ello

```
#creamos un método para dar valores al array y llamar al método
Depends(){
    #creamos el array y le damos los valores
    dependencies=( "build-essential" "git" "...") 
    #llamamos al método y le enviamos el array por parámetro
    insDepends ${dependencies[@]} 
}
#el método al que llamamos
insDepends(){ 
    #recibe el array por parámetro y duarda sus valores en el array name
    name=("${@}") 
    #lo imprimimos para comprobar que le han llegado los valores
    echo "${name[*]}"

    #hacemos un bucle para recorrer el array
    for depend in ${name[@]}
    do 
        #por cada iteración del bucle hace un install del valor del array
        #esta línea es en la que me arroja un error por cada iteración
        #lo probé en una terminal on-line y no tengo ese sistema de archivos, esperemos que en tu caso si funcione
        sudo apt-get install $depend -y > /dev/null 
    done 
}
#iniciamos el programa llamando a la primer función
Depends
```

Comment: He probado como indicas y no me funciona, algo hago mal
Podrias poner el ejemplo resuelto de como tendria que hacerlo?
Lo he hecho así y tampoco funciona
```
dependencies=( "build-essential" "git" ...)
insDepends "${dependencies[@]}"
function insDepends(){
name=(  "${@}"  )
for depend in "${name[@]}";do
apt install $depend -y > /dev/null
done
}
```
Esta vez he cambiado como recibir el array en la función, name=( "${@}" )
Lo he puesto como lo indicas en primer ejemplo pero nada
No se si está mal como le paso los parametros o si esta mal el recibirlos en la funcion
@el.trasgu

Comment: Acabo de editar mi respuesta y agragar tu código en ella. Te pido disculpas porque en mi respuesta me habían quedado comillas en la variable y el array que se enviaba por parámetro, eidentemente no era lo correcto. Ya está corregido. A ver si ahora te sirve, aunque a mí me da error en la línea de la instalación de los paquetes. Un saludo